# My compressed image has no dimensions android

Tags: kotlin

I use this function to compress images:

```
    private fun takeScreenshot() {
    val now = Date()
    DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now)
    val now2= now.toString().split(" ")
    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        val mPath: String =
            getExternalFilesDir(null).toString().toString() + "/" + now2 + ".png"
        Log.d("path",mPath)
        // create bitmap screen capture
        val v1 = window.decorView.rootView
        v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.drawingCache)
        v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
        val imageFile = File(mPath)

        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
        val quality = 100
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream)
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

And after do it,the result is a png file with no dimensions,i can't open it and view on laptop but can view on phone:

[image]

How to add dimensions?

Comment: Did you already try rename the file to a more simple name? Like "file.png", then try to open up this file again. Also did you already try to open one up with some graphic editor like Gimp or Photoshop?

Comment: @JorgeLuiz when i copy this image to a new folder size of it is up and it have dimensions so i think the code have problem.